# Jython wrong type of parameter passed?

Tags: python, jython

I'm pretty new to python, but I know type casting is usually based on whether or not you need it to stay the type you want it to be. I'm trying to do some basic arithemetic but when I try to pass the variables holding the numbers, it says it is a invalid type.

```
def doublePicture():
  a = pickAFile()
  b = makePicture(a)
  c = getWidth(b)
  d = getHeight(b)
  e = c * 1.5
  f = d *1.5
  newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(e,f)
```

ERROR:
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.

Comment: Can you post the actual exception traceback?  These things are easier to decipher if you give us that.

Comment: sure thing, will make an edit now.